# Применение SVG filter совместно CSS transitions

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, css-animation

Я сделал  svg-фильтр с анимацией css:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
   </filter>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

И применил его к контейнеру CSS.

```
filter:url('#goo');
```

[Здесь пример](https://codepen.io/sergey_mell/pen/MoRMwR)

И я застрял в следующем вопросе:

Анимация выполняется внутри какого-то окна (размер зависит от размера начальной анимации).

Может ли кто-нибудь помочь  мне  устранить  это?

Источник: [SVG filter with CSS transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45146779/7394871) @Sergey Mell

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45146779/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Фильтры SVG имеют определенный `filter region`, внутри которого применяются эффекты.
Это вызвано тем, что некоторые операции могут быть очень медленными (например, гауссовское размытие), и поэтому область ограничена, внутри которой происходят вычисления.

Область действия фильтра по умолчанию:

`x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%"`

Другими словами, к элементу, который фильтруется, добавляется 10% -ная граница вокруг него.
Все, что находится за пределами этой области, будет обрезано (и невидимо).

Решение состоит в том, чтобы увеличить область действия фильтра так, чтобы она охватывала все ваши капли.

Так, например, если мы увеличим `margin` до 50%

`<filter id="goo" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">`

то теперь фильтр работает правильно.

```css
body{
  background:white;
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/d47ZIU3.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
}
.blobs{
  filter:url('#goo');
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:200px;
}

@keyframes blob-left-top-anim{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
  33%{
    transform:scale(0.9) translate(-65px,0);
  }
  62%{
    transform:scale(0.7) translate(-65px,-65px);

  }
  94%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
}

@keyframes blob-right-top-anim{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
  33%{
    transform:scale(0.9) translate(65px,0);
  }
  64%{
    transform:scale(0.7) translate(65px,-65px);
  }
  96%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
}
@keyframes blob-left-bottom-anim{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
  33%{
    transform:scale(0.9) translate(-65px,0);
  }
  66%{
    transform:scale(0.7) translate(-65px,65px);
  }
  98%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
}

@keyframes blob-right-bottom-anim{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
  33%{
    transform:scale(0.9) translate(65px,0);
  }
  68%{
    transform:scale(0.7) translate(65px,65px);
  }
  100%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
}
.blob{
  position:absolute;
  background:#e97b7a;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  border-radius:100%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  animation:blob-left-top-anim cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000) 4s infinite;
}

  
.blob:nth-child(2){
  animation-name:blob-right-top-anim;
}
.blob:nth-child(3){
  animation-name:blob-left-bottom-anim;
}
.blob:nth-child(4){
  animation-name:blob-right-bottom-anim;
}
```

```html
<div class="blobs">
  <div class="blob">4</div>
  <div class="blob">3</div>
  <div class="blob">2</div>
  <div class="blob">1</div>
</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
   </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [SVG filter with CSS transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45214454/7394871) @Paul LeBeau